# Pass store_id to catalog/product

Tags: collection, multistore, eav

Thanks Marius for Reply.
I am new to Magento and I don't know how EAV works. I want to know, how to pass store_id and attribute_id to

```
protected function genericView($attribute, $code) {
   $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId();           
   $attr = Mage::getModel('eav/entity_attribute')->getCollection()->addFieldToFilter('frontend_label', $code);
   $attribute = $attr->getData('attribute_code');
   $attribute_id=$attribute[0]['attribute_id'];
   $attributecode=$attribute[0]['attribute_code'];
   $collection=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()
                ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
                ->addAttributeToFilter(array(array('attribute' => $attributecode,'null' => '')));
   $collection->printLogQuery(true);
        ........
        ........
}
```

output for above `$collection` is

```
SELECT `e`.*, `at_bluesta00032`.`value` AS `bluesta00032` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_entity_varchar` AS `at_bluesta00032` ON (`at_bluesta00032`.`entity_id` = `e`.`entity_id`) AND (`at_bluesta00032`.`attribute_id` = '1023') AND (`at_bluesta00032`.`store_id` = 0) WHERE ((at_bluesta00032.value IS NULL))
```

In above `$collection(query)` store_id is always "0", for different stores.So, I want to pass respective store_id for different Stores. Can You, please provide solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thankyou very much Marius, for Your inputs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question is not much clear. As I understood so far if you want to embed the store id and attribute set id in product collection, it's already in the product collection. 
Try this code snippet.

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection();

    foreach($collection as $product) {
        $storeId = $product->getStoreId();
        $attributeSetId = $product->getAttributeSetId();break;
        // Do something 
    }
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for Solution Sukeshini

Comment: :) Glad it helps you

Answer (score 1):

To add the store to the product collection you need to use the function `addStoreFilter`. This will add a filter.

> Add store availability filter. Include availability product for store
>   website

So your code would probably look as follows:

```
$collection = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->getCollection()->addStoreFilter($store_id);
```

Comment: Thankyou very much for Solution David

Comment: @Naruto hope it helped :)

Comment: It helped me David :)